# Looping through ul li and using insertBefore to move image up two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am learning js and  jquery and have  been trying to solve this litle issue I am having when trying to loop through a ul on the page and move a dom element specifically an image up two levels in my html. Here is what the html looks like:

```
<ul class="feedEkList">
    <li class="slick-slide">
        <div class="featured-title">
            <div class="post-title">
                <a href="some url" target="_blank">some text</a>
            </div>
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <img src="imageurl.jpg" class="wp-post-image">
                <p>Post Description.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are 10 li items in my ul but for readability purpose I only included one so you can see my html structure.

My javascript seems to be adding all the images before every featured-title div giving me piles of pictures instead of the one that is associated with that li.

```
$(function() {
    $('.wp-post-image').insertBefore($('.featured-title'));

});
```

So then I tried this using each but it does not seem to do anything.

```
$(function() {
$('.feedEkList > li > .featured-title > .post-excerpt > .wp-post-image').each(function() {
    $('.wp-post-image').insertBefore($('.featured-title'));
    });
});
```

I was thinking maybe i need to use "this" in the code somewhere but I am new to javascript and not sure how to properly use "this" with the insert before, or if "this" is even the best option.

```
$('this.wp-post-image').insertBefore($('this.featured-title'));
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? It is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to iterate **each** image
2. For **each** image, get his parent `.slick-slide`.
3. Prepend the image to the `.slick-slide` using [`.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)
4. Optional: If you need to insertBefore `.featured-title` see the comment.

```js
$('.wp-post-image').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      parentLi = $this.parents('.slick-slide').first();
  
  $this.prependTo(parentLi);
  //$this.insertBefore(parentLi.find('.featured-title'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="feedEkList">
  <li class="slick-slide">
    <div class="featured-title">
      <div class="post-title">
        <a href="some url" target="_blank">some text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="post-excerpt">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgiPG.jpg" class="wp-post-image" />
        <p>Post Description.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="slick-slide">
    <div class="featured-title">
      <div class="post-title">
        <a href="some url" target="_blank">some text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="post-excerpt">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgiPG.jpg" class="wp-post-image" />
        <p>Post Description.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="slick-slide">
    <div class="featured-title">
      <div class="post-title">
        <a href="some url" target="_blank">removed the "wp-post-image" class to show how it was look before</a>
      </div>
      <div class="post-excerpt">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgiPG.jpg" />
        <p>Post Description.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Mosh! Your great and thanks for shedding some light on this. I do have one follow up to this though. I took your code and it does work if I run this code in the console, I get the perfect result. If I use it on page or as an attached .js I cant seem to get it to work. Here is what I have done so far. I added a document ready thinking maybe the DOM was not ready when the script ran. Unfortunately it still does not run unless it is in the console.  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
with your code inside here  });

Comment: My pleasure ;) `Here is what I have done so far`. Where?

Comment: sorry I guess that was not very clear.                                                      <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.wp-post-image').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      parentLi = $this.parents('.slick-slide').first();
    $this.insertBefore(parentLi.find('.featured-title'));
});                }); 


</script>

Comment: Can you create a [bin](http://jsbin.com/) for this? because I can't see something wrong. Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: Mosh just to follow up, the code does work and in paste bin it works. I believe the problem may be with shopify as that is where I am using the code. I am not sure how they work but over the course of the day all of a sudden it works on shop preview. Maybe they have something cached or they deliver from different servers..not too sure but the important thing is that it does work! Thanks a million Mosh!